# NullPointerException for JButton

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I am trying to assign text to buttons inside a loop but I am getting an NullPointerException.
I have initialized the button array inside constructor of the class and after initilizatoin, I call the following method. Here is the code where I am getting error.

```
public class Alfred
{
   private String names[]={"nfs","gta","maxpayne","hitman"};
   private JButton but[];

   public Alfred()
   {
    ...
     but= new JButton[4];
    AssignLettersToButtons();
   }
    private void AssignLettersToButtons()
    {       
        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            but[i].setText(names[i]); // error
            pane1.add(but[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The length of button array and names array is same. What is the reason for this exception and how can I solve it?

Regards

Comment: Can we see the initialization code for those two arrays?

Comment: It's a null pointer exception, so you're just calling a method on something null. Depending on whether it's the first or second line in your loop, it's either but[i] or pane1. The most likely situation is that but[i] isn't a button as you expected due to some bug in initialization.

Comment: What does debugging reveal about where exactly the npe is thrown?

Comment: Does your button array contain button objects in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 but= new JButton[4];
```

This only **allocates space** for four array elements; each element is [initialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) to `null`, the *default value* for a reference type like your `JButton` objects.

`but[0]`, `but[1]`, `but[2]`, `but[3]` are all `null`.

You should **initialize** them like this:

```
but[0] = new JButton(); //or whatever.
```

Comment: In particular, each array component is [initialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) to a _default value_, which is `null` for a reference type such as `JButton`.

Answer (score 1):

You havn't initialized the elements in the `but` array.

If you want to do the initialization in the loop you could simplify it to:

```
for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    pane1.add(but[i] = new JButton(names[i]));
```

Comment: Then the `pane1` (`JPanel`?) is `null`, create it in the constructor using `pane1 = new JPanel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
  but[i].setText(names[i]); //but[i] is null here
```

Initialize the but array before calling method on it

and instantiate the elements inside array  as they all are null Just see

```
   for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(but[i]);//all will print null
    }
```

try code like this to instantiate the elements also

```
   for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
       but[i]= new Jbutton();
    }
```

Comment: But still your array elemnets are null .Intantiate elments inside array

Answer (score 0):

if the size of the but array is 5. Add 5 but objects in it before you do the following:

```
but[i].setText(names[i]);
```

I think your array has not been initialized with but objects, that's why when you do `setText()` it gives you NPE.

Try something as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            JButton butObject = new JButton();//Add this line to your code
            but[i]=butObject;         // Add this line to your code
            but[i].setText(names[i]); // error
            pane1.add(but[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java initializes your array of type JButton to 0 (aka NULL). You need to initialize each index of the array to be a pointer to an instance of JButton, as it does not call the constructor automatically for each element.